# Is it Possible to get an Element by Text and remove it using bs4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the Website I'm scraping: `biharjobportal.com`
The detail Page has multiple `<p` Tags, but Im specifically looking for the <p tag which has **biharjobportal.com** in it :

```
<p>बिहार में निकलने वाली सारी एडमिशन, रिजल्ट और नौकरी की जानकारी इस वेबसाइट पर प्रदान की जाएगी | इसलिए इस वेबसाइट पर आने के लिए हमें गूगल में&nbsp;<strong>biharjobportal.com</strong>&nbsp;टाइप करे |</p>
```

As you can see, it has the Text `biharjobportal.com` is present. I wonder if it is possible to locate the Tag with `biharjobportal.com` and `decompose()` it.

This is what I have tried :

```
getptags = entry_content.find_all('p')
if 'biharjobportal.com' in getptags:
    #decompose() code here
else:
    print('nothing to decompose')
```

The `entry_content` is the root Element. The Output of above code always executes the else part, even though `biharjobportal.com` is present in it.
Please Guide me. Thanks

Comment: Post needs further clarification, are you trying to locate the `<strong>` tag within soup or are you content to `decompose()` the entire text w/in the p element if it contains your target string?

In any case, the missing ingredients here are manually looping over the content and appropriate use of `in tag.text` which will just extract the string value under a tag

Comment: Im trying to remove the entire <p Tag if the text is found.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are asking if a string is in a list of `bs4.element.Tag` objects.  The `in` operator applied to a list will only return true if there is an exact match of one of the objects in the list.

The missing part is 1) you need to loop over each `Tag` in the list you get back from find_all and 2) you need to use the `text` attribute before doing your contains comparison.  Something like

```
getptags = entry_content.find_all('p')
for tag in getptags:
    if 'biharjobportal.com' in tag.text:
        #decompose() code here
    else:
        print('nothing to decompose')
```

Comment: ok, I'm trying and letting you know. Will it not interfere with other text inside the p tag ? I mean there are other words too. Will it find the exact match?

Comment: The if statement as written will evaluate to `True` if the `tag.text` string contains the target string 'biharjobportal.com' anywhere in the text contained inside the p tag.  If you wanted only an exact match to work, you could do something like `if 'biharjobportal.com' == tag.text:` instead

Comment: thanks for the help. will try and let u know asap